# function pointer without typedef

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, typedef, syntactic-sugar

Is it posible to use the type of a prefiously declared function as a function pointer without using a typedef?

function declaration:

```
int myfunc(float);
```

use the function declaration by some syntax as function pointer

```
myfunc* ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc = 0;
```

Comment: You want a function pointer that can only point to your own delcared function?

Comment: @wheaties I want a function pointer to a function with the same signature as myfunc

Comment: Are you aware you can apply `typedef` to functions declarations to typedef their type? `typedef int myfunc(float); myfunc *ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc = 0;`? Most people are not aware of this and think they need the ugly `(*foo)` syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not as per the 2003 standard. Yes, with the upcoming C++0x standard and MSVC 2010 and g++ 4.5:

```
decltype(myfunc)* ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc = 0;
```

Comment: the problem is my code does not compile with c++0x enabled. So this is no usable solution for me :S

Comment: With g++ you can use `typeof(myfunc)` instead of `decltype(myfunc)` and it works even in non-C++0x mode.

Comment: for me this solution is not usable but I will accept this as an answer. Perhaps I will change my code until it compiles with c++0x.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to declare a function pointer without a typedef, but no it is not possible to use the name of a function to do that.

The typedef is usually used because the syntax for declaring a function pointer is a bit baroque. However, the typedef is not required. You can write:

```
int (*ptr)(float);
```

to declare `ptr` as a function pointer to a function taking `float` and returning `int` -- no typedef is involved. But again, there is no syntax that will allow you to use the name `myfunc` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it posible to use the type of a prefiously declared function as a function pointer without using a typedef?

I'm going to cheat a bit

```
template<typename T>
void f(T *f) {
  T* ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc = 0;
}

f(&myfunc);
```

Of course, this is not completely without pitfalls: It uses the function, so it must be defined, whereas such things as `decltype` do not use the function and do not require the function to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at the present time. C++0x will change the meaning of `auto`, and add a new keyword `decltype` that lets you do things like this. If you're using gcc/g++, you might also look into using its `typeof` operator, which is quite similar (has a subtle difference when dealing with references).

Answer (score 1):

No, not without C++0x `decltype`:

```
int myfunc(float)
{
  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  decltype (myfunc) * ptr = myfunc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

gcc has `typeof` as an extension for C (don't know about C++) ( http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html ).

```
int myfunc(float);

int main(void) {
    typeof(myfunc) *ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc;
    ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GCC doesn't need the `typeof` extension in C++ because it implements the (soon to be standard) `decltype`, which serves pretty much the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*ptrWithSameTypeAsMyFunc)(float) = 0;
```

See [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) for more info on the basics.